# How to use vorticiy calculation in metpy version 1.0?

Tags: python, metpy

I want to used `metpy.calc.vorticity`. Previously, its structure was `(u, v, dx, dy)`, but change to `(u, v, *, dx=None, dy=None, x_dim=- 1, y_dim=- 2)`.

1. What is `*` at the new structure?
2. When I use `(u, v)`, it seems other arguments are optional, I faced `ValueError: Must provide dx/dy arguments or input DataArray with latitude/longitude coordinates.`
3. When I used `(u , v, dx, dy)`, I faced `TypeError: too many positional arguments`.

However, I don't have problem with `geostrophic_wind(height,dx,dy,latitude)` in my code and my data, but what is the problem with vorticity?
Some parts of my code is as below:

```py
PATH_nc = '/home/python_script/'
out_fff='gfs.t12z.pgrb2.0p50.f168'
ncfile = Dataset('{}{}.nc'.format(PATH_nc,out_fff))
lon = ncfile.variables['longitude'][:]
lon[lon < 0] = 360 + lon[lon < 0]
lat = ncfile.variables['latitude'][:]
dx, dy = mpcalc.lat_lon_grid_deltas(lon, lat)
long1, lat1 = np.meshgrid(lon, lat)
hght_850  = ncfile.variables['HGT_850mb'][:]
HGT_850  = gaussian_filter((hght_850)/10, sigma=  2)
height850 = ndimage.gaussian_filter(hght_850, sigma=1.5, order=0)
geo_wind_u_850, geo_wind_v_850 = mpcalc.geostrophic_wind(np.squeeze(height850)*units.m, dx, dy, lat1)
vwnd_700 =  units('m/s') *ncfile.variables['VGRD_700mb'][:]
avor700 = mpcalc.vorticity(np.squeeze(uwnd_700), np.squeeze(vwnd_700), dx, dy)
```

I hope to write all necessary parts of my code, related to the problem.
I'll be thankful for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So in the definition of `vorticity`:

```
metpy.calc.vorticity(u, v, *, dx=None, dy=None, x_dim=-1, y_dim=-2)
```

Everything after the `*` is defined as a [keyword-only argument](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-parameter), which means the function argument/parameter can only be passed via keyword. Because your current code is not passing `dx` and `dy` via keyword, but only by position, this is by the error you get is: `TypeError: too many positional arguments`. The fix is to pass `dx` and `dy` using keyword arguments as:

```
avor700 = mpcalc.vorticity(np.squeeze(uwnd_700), np.squeeze(vwnd_700), dx=dx, dy=dy)
```